# Custom STRCAT is overwhelmed by too many arguments

Tags: c, arguments, concatenation, strcat

I am trying to code a custom `strcat` that separates arguments with `\n` except for the last one and terminates the string with `\0`.

It's working fine as is up to 5 arguments, but if I try passing a sixth one I get a strange line in response :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Domingo% ./test ok ok ok ok ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
MacBook-Pro-de-Domingo% ./test ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
P/Users/domingodelmasok
```

Here is my custom `strcat` code:

```
char    cat(char *dest, char *src, int current, int argc_nb)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(dest[i])
        i++;

    while(src[j])
    {
        dest[i + j] = src[j];
        j++;
    }

    if(current < argc_nb - 1)
        dest[i + j] = '\n';
    else
        dest[i + j] = '\0';

    return(*dest);
}
```

**UPDATE** Complete calling function:

```
char    *concator(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int size = 0;
    char *str;

    i = 1;

    while(i < argc)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(argv[i][j])
        {
            size++;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*str) * (size + 1));

    i = 1;

   while(i < argc)
   {
        cat(str, argv[i], i, argc);
        i++;
    }

    free(str);
    return(str);
}
```

What's wrong here?

Thanks!

Edit: Fixed blunder.

Comment: `dest` needs to be initialized with the required length and filled with zeros. Can you show the full code?

Comment: Don't assume that the problem is not in the code you're not showing.

Comment: @klutt I updated the question with the full code :) Sorry about that

Comment: @Domso I updated the question

Comment: This code only calculates the length of the **last** command line argument ... you reset `j` to `0` each time. probably, you wanted to use `size` in your `malloc()`.

Comment: just using a destination buffer of reasonable length and counting as you append would be easier anyways (and the idiomatic C way to do it).

Comment: @FelixPalmen You're right about `size` and `malloc`, thanks! Big blunder on my part here. Fixing that didn't fix the issue tho, it seems to come from `\n`..

Comment: the size of your buffer **is** the issue. You also forget to add the space for all the `\n` characters. with your code, `str = malloc(size + argc);` would be correct, I guess. (use this concise form. casting `void *` is completely superfluous and the size of a `char` is 1 *by definition*)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thank you very much Felix. `malloc(size + 1 + argc)` did it! You were right about me forgetting space for the `\n's`

Comment: @FelixPalmen Why does `(char*)malloc(sizeof(*str) * (size + 1 + argc))` do not work and `malloc(size + 1 + argc)` does tho?

Comment: The `+1` is unnecessary, you append one extra character for each argument, in sum `argc` characters. Apart from that: both statements are exactly the same, given `str` has type `char *` and the result is assigned to a `char *`.

Comment: Just spotted another bug: Your `cat()` function expects the whole buffer to be zeroed-out. Better write a `\0` **every** time, then you only have to zero the first element before the first call. Right now, your whole program fails if the memory returned by `malloc()` isn't zeroed by coincidence.

Comment: How can I `write a \0 every time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with the code:

- `sizeof (char) == 1` by the C standard.
- `cat()` requires the destination to be a string (terminated by a `\0`), but does not append it itself (except for `current >= argc_nb - 1`). This is a bug.
- `free(str); return str;` is an use-after-free bug.  If you call `free(str)`, the contents at `str` are irrevocably lost, inaccessible. The `free(str)` should simply be removed; it is not appropriate here.
- Arrays in C are indexed at 0. However, the `concator()` function skips the first string pointer (because `argv[0]` contains the name used to execute the program). This is wrong, and will eventually trip someone.  Instead, have `concator()` add all strings in the array, but call it using `concator(argc - 1, argv + 1);`.

There might be even more, but at this point, I believe a rewrite from scratch, using a much more appropriate approach, is in order.

Consider the following `join()` function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *join(const size_t parts, const char *part[],
           const char *separator, const char *suffix)
{
    const size_t separator_len = (separator) ? strlen(separator) : 0;
    const size_t suffix_len = (suffix) ? strlen(suffix) : 0;
    size_t       total_len = 0;
    size_t       p;
    char        *dst, *end;

    /* Calculate sum of part lengths */
    for (p = 0; p < parts; p++)
        if (part[p])
            total_len += strlen(part[p]);

    /* Add separator lengths */
    if (parts > 1)
        total_len += (parts - 1) * separator_len;

    /* Add suffix length */
    total_len += suffix_len;

    /* Allocate enough memory, plus end-of-string '\0' */
    dst = malloc(total_len + 1);
    if (!dst)
        return NULL;

    /* Keep a pointer to the current end of the result string */
    end = dst;

    /* Append each part */
    for (p = 0; p < parts; p++) {

        /* Insert separator */
        if (p > 0 && separator_len > 0) {
            memcpy(end, separator, separator_len);
            end += separator_len;
        }

        /* Insert part */
        if (part[p]) {
            const size_t  len = strlen(part[p]);
            if (len > 0) {
                memcpy(end, part[p], len);
                end += len;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Append suffix */
    if (suffix_len > 0) {
        memcpy(end, suffix, suffix_len);
        end += suffix_len;
    }

    /* Terminate string. */
    *end = '\0';

    /* All done. */
    return dst;
}
```

The logic is simple. First, we find out the length of each component.  Note that `separator` is only added between parts (so occurs `parts-1` times), and `suffix` at the very end.

(The `(string) ? strlen(string) : 0` idiom just means *"if `string` is non-NULL, `strlen(0)`, otherwise `0`"*. We do that, because we allow NULL separator and suffix, but `strlen(NULL)` is Undefined Behaviour.)

Next, we allocate enough memory for the result, including the end-of-string NUL char, `\0`, that was not included in the lengths.

To append each part, we keep the result pointer intact, and instead use a temporary `end` pointer. (It is the end of the string thus far.) We use a loop, where we copy the next part to the `end`. Before the second and subsequent parts, we copy the separator before the part.

Next, we copy the suffix, and finally the end-of-string `'\0'`.  (It is important to return a pointer to the beginning of the string, rather than end, of course; and that is why we kept `dst` to point to the new resulting string, and `end` at the point we appended each substring.)

You could use it from the command line using for example the following `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *result;

    if (argc < 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s SEPARATOR SUFFIX PART [ PART ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    result = join(argc - 3, (const char **)(argv + 3), argv[1], argv[2]);
    if (!result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fputs(result, stdout);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you compile the above to e.g. `example` (I use `gcc -Wall -O2 example.c -o example`), then running

```
./example ', ' $'!\n' Hello world
```

in a Bash shell outputs

```
Hello, world!
```

(with a newline at end). Running

```
./example ' and ' $'.\n' a b c d e f g
```

outputs

```
a and b and c and d and e and f and g
```

(again with a newline at end). The `$'...'` is just a Bash idiom to specify special characters in strings; `$'!\n'` is the same in Bash as `"!\n"` is in C, and `$'.\n'` is the Bash equivalent of `".\n"` in C.

(Removing the automatic newline between parts, and allowing a string rather than just one char to be used as a separator and suffix, was a deliberate choice for two reasons. The main one is to stop anyone from just copy-pasting this as an answer to some exercise. The secondary one is to show that while it might *sound* more complicated than just using single characters for them, it is actually very little additional code; and if you consider the practical use cases, allowing a string to be used as the separator opens up a lot of options.)

The example code above is only very lightly tested, and might contain bugs. If you find any, or disagree with anything I've written above, do let me know in a comment so I can review, and fix as necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is very instructive for a beginner like me!